# Hadoop distcp command using a different S3 destination

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, eucalyptus, distcp

I am using a Eucalyptus private cloud on which I have set up an CDH5 HDFS. I would like to backup my HDFS to the Eucalyptus S3. The classic way to use distcp as suggested here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 , ie `hadoop distp hdfs://namenode:9000/user/foo/data/fil1 s3://$AWS_ACCESS_KEY:$AWS_SECRET_KEY@bucket/key` doesn't work.

It seems that hadoop is pre-configured with an S3 location on Amazon and I cannot find where is this configuration in order to change this to the IP address of my S3 service running on Eucalyptus. I would expect to be able to just change the uri of S3 in the same way you can change your NameNode uri when using an hdfs:// prefix. But is seems this is not possible... Any insights?

I have already found workarounds for transferring my data. In particular the s3cmd tools here: https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/HowTo-use-s3cmd-with-Eucalyptus and the s3curl scripts here: aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-S3/2880343845151917 work just fine but I would prefer if I could transfer my data using map-reduce with the distcp command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like hadoop is using the jets3t library for S3 access. You might be able to use the configuration described [in this blog](http://jamesmurty.com/2009/04/30/how-to-use-jets3t-with-eucalyptus/) to access eucalyptus, but note that for version 4 onwards the path is "/services/objectstorage" rather than "/services/Walrus".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't manage to make it work completely but your answer helped me move a little bit further. It seems that in my case distcp works with s3n:// but it doesn't with s3://. In the later case I get a 404 error "The specified entity was not found" which I am yet unsure how to solve. I have added configuration to core-site.xml and created a jets3t.properties file as suggested on your link and some other related links I found for jets3t.